# Search and replace visual block only?

Tags: search, visual-block

How do I search and replace in a visual block only?

`'<,'>s/search/replace/` works on entire lines, not visual blocks only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\%V` (`:h \%V`) to do that:

```
:%s/\%Vsearch/replace/
```